# Python: Compare adjacent column based on primary key

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Please refer this link to see data [pandas merge two dataframe and sort by compared column in adjacent column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74585876/pandas-merge-two-dataframe-and-sort-by-compared-column-in-adjacent-column#76326061)

How can I compare adjacent column here based on primary key which is Id1 and ID2 here, example : Lang_1 with Lang_2 , Mat_1 with Mat_2 and so on and if any mismatch b/w adjacent column found for that particular row then Status should be fail and if all adjacent column will match then pass how I can do that. Can anyone please help me.

```
import pandas as pd

exam_1 = {
  'ID1': ['1', '2', '3', '3', '5', '5'],
  'ID2': ['1', '1', '4', '5', '1', '2'],
  'Mat': [80, 75, 50, 93, 88, 90],
  'Science': [96, 97, 99, 87, 90, 88],
}

exam_2 = {
  'ID1': ['1', '2', '3', '3', '5'],
  'ID2': ['1', '1', '4', '5', '1'],
  'Mat': [80, np.nan , 50, 93, 88],
  'Science': [50, 60, 85, 90, 66],
}
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(exam_1)
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(exam_2)

cmp =  pd.merge(df_1, df_2, how="outer", on=['ID1','Id2'], suffixes=("_1", "_2"))
            .set_index('ID1','ID2')
            .sort_index(axis=1)
            .reset_index()

cmp['Status'] = cmp.iloc[:, 2:].apply(lambda x: 'Pass' if x[0]==x[1] else 'Fail', axis =1)
```

Below two scenarios I want to cover

1. If Primary key of df1 is present in df2
   a) if both adjacent cell match then it should be highlighted with green
   b)if both adjacent cell is not matching then it should be highlighted with red color
   c) if any cell is blank then yellow
2. If primary key of df1 is not present in df2
   Whole row should be highlighted with yellow color except primary key.

Answer (score 0):

Modified code:

```py
import pandas as pd

exam_1 = {
  'ID1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
  'ID2': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
  'Mat': [85, 75, 50, 93, 88, 90],
  'Science': [96, 97, 99, 87, 90, 88],
  'Reading': [80, 60, 72, 86, 84, 77],
  'Writing': [78, 82, 88, 78, 86, 82],
  'Lang': [77, 79, 77, 72, 90, 92],
}

exam_2 = {
  'ID1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
  'ID2': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
  'Mat': [80, 80, 90, 90, 85, 80],
  'Science': [50, 60, 85, 90, 66, 82],
  'Reading': [60, 75, 55, 90, 85, 60],
  'Writing': [56, 66, 90, 82, 60, 80],
  'Lang': [80, 78, 76, 90, 77, 66],
}

df_1 = pd.DataFrame(exam_1)
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(exam_2)

cmp = pd.merge(df_1, df_2, how="outer", on=['ID1', 'ID2'], suffixes=("_1", "_2")) \
    .set_index(['ID1', 'ID2']) \
    .sort_index(axis=1) \
    .reset_index()

cmp['Status'] = cmp.iloc[:, 3:].apply(lambda x: 'Pass' if x[0] == x[1] else 'Fail', axis=1)
```

Here's what changed:

1. Added `'ID1'` and `'ID2'` to the exam data dictionaries to match the column names in the merge operation.
2. Fixed the typo in the column name `'Writing'`.
3. Added `'ID1'` and `'ID2'` to the `set_index` function to set the index of the DataFrame.
4. Adjusted the `iloc` indexing in the `apply` function to start from the third column (`iloc[:, 3:]`) to exclude the non-comparable columns.
5. Modified the `lambda` function to return `'Pass'` if the adjacent values are equal (`x[0] == x[1]`) and `'Fail'` otherwise.

After these changes, the `cmp` DataFrame will contain the columns `ID1`, `ID2`, and the original columns from both `df_1` and `df_2`. The `Status` column will indicate whether the adjacent values in each row match or not.

Comment: Thank you but why you added Name field in both dataframe

Comment: Please disregard. I was testing and doing some copy paste with the data. the name field is irrelevant. It is my bad.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can use :

```
cmp =  (
    pd.merge(df_1, df_2, how="outer", on=["ID1", "ID2"], suffixes=("_1", "_2"))
        .set_index(["ID1", "ID2"]).sort_index(axis=1)
)
            
cmp["Status"] = (
    np.where(
        (cmp.filter(like="_1").to_numpy() == cmp.filter(like="_2").to_numpy())
            .all(axis=1), "Pass", "Fail")
)

#or, use your approach
#cmp["Status"] = cmp.apply(lambda x: "Pass" if x[0]==x[1] else "Fail", axis=1)

cmp = cmp.reset_index()
```

Output :

```
print(cmp)

  ID1 ID2  Lang_1  Lang_2  ...  Science_2  Wiritng_1  Wiritng_2  Status
0   1   1      77      80  ...         50         78         56    Fail
1   2   1      79      78  ...         60         82         66    Fail
2   3   4      77      76  ...         85         88         90    Fail
3   3   5      72      90  ...         90         78         82    Fail
4   5   1      90      77  ...         66         86         60    Fail
5   5   2      92      66  ...         82         82         80    Fail
```

***Update :***

> *Below two scenarios I want to cover :*
>
> If Primary key of df1 is present in df2
>
> - a) if both adjacent cell match then it should be highlighted with green
> - b) if both adjacent cell is not matching then it should be highlighted with red color
> - c) if any cell is blank then yellow
>
> If primary key of df1 is not present in df2 :
>
> - Whole row should be highlighted with yellow color except primary key.

```
cmp =  (
    pd.merge(df_1, df_2, how="outer", on=["ID1", "ID2"],
             suffixes=("_1", "_2"), indicator=True)
        .set_index(["ID1", "ID2"]).sort_index(axis=1).reset_index()
)

is_match = cmp.pop("_merge").eq("both")

def color_match(df):
    tmp = df.set_index(["ID1", "ID2"]).reset_index(drop=True)
    l = tmp.eq(tmp.shift(-1, axis=1)).mul(is_match, axis=0)
    r = tmp.eq(tmp.shift(+1, axis=1)).mul(is_match, axis=0)
    
    pairs = l.add(r).replace(
        {True: "background-color: lightgreen",
         False: "background-color: lightcoral"})
        
    ids = pd.DataFrame(
        "", columns=cmp[["ID1", "ID2"]].columns,
        index=cmp[["ID1", "ID2"]].index)

    return pd.concat([ids, pairs], axis=1)

def color_diff(_):
    return np.where(~is_match, "background-color: yellow", "")

pd.set_option("styler.format.precision", 0)
(
    cmp.style.apply(color_match, axis=None)
     .apply(color_diff, axis=0, subset=cmp.iloc[:, 2:].columns)
     .highlight_null(color="yellow")
     # .to_excel("output.xlsx", index=False) #uncomment to make a spreadsheet
)
```

[image]

Comment: How can I add color here if suppose for any row adjacent column is not matching backgrounf of both cell should be highlighted with red if matching then green and if one of them is blank then yellow.

Comment: Yes it is possible to do so but you need to give a reproducible example of `df_1` and `df_2` that hold data with all the different scenarios you're describing in your comment above (*in order to have a meaningful styling*). Also, do you need to color only the `Status` column or the whole row ?

Comment: I updated the scenario which i want to cover can you please help.

Comment: All right but are you sure that the given examples (the actual values of `df_1` and `df_2`) cover all the scenarios ?

Comment: Updated df1 and df2

Comment: Can you tell me why you used 2 in subset = cmp.iloc[:,2].columns and when I am running this code it's throwing error: No such keys(s): ' styler.format.precision'

Comment: `1)` the code `subset = cmp.iloc[:, 2:].columns` is used to exclude the columns of the primary keys when applying the styles `2)` The code runs without any problem in `2.0.1`. Either upgrade your pandas version (*with* `pip install --upgrade pandas`) or remove this line `pd.set_option("styler.format.precision", 0)`.